# How to replay webp in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I'm currently working on a project in Flutter. Specifically, I'm working on a problem, which contains the following code:

```dart
Image.asset('images/icon.webp')
```

This code is used to display a webp animation in my app. However, I'm having trouble getting the animation to loop indefinitely. Currently, the animation only plays once and then stops.

I've tried using the `ImageRepeat` property of the `DecorationImage` widget to repeat the animation, but it doesn't seem to work with webp files.

For ExtendedImage I also tried but also not working.

```dart
import 'package:extended_image/extended_image.dart';

ExtendedImage.asset(
  'images/icon.webp',
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,
);
```

Does anyone know of a way to make a webp animation repeat in a loop in Flutter? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use loop playback when making webp files
For example, when using `ffmpeg` to make webp files, you can use `-loop 0` to set loop playback
For example:

```
ffmpeg -i icon%05d.png -lossless 1 -loop 0 icon.webp
```